# Is it necessary to use "a" before "lot" in a sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence

Which one of the following is grammatically correct -

1. He is going through lot of stress.
2. He is going through a lot of stress

On one of online platforms it suggested to use **a lot**

Comment: Yes, it's _a lot of_ or, more informally, _lots of_. You may find the English Language Learners forum more suitable for you. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Yes, although singular "lot" is a non-count noun here, it still requires the determiner "a". Note that it can also have plural obliques, as in "A lot of errors were made", though it still requires the determiner "a".

Comment: Reference: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lot (This says that both "a lot" and "lots of" are informal, but in my opinion you could use "a lot" in most contexts).

Comment: _Lot_ in this construction is a count noun, meaning 'definite assortment', and as such it requires either an article in the singular, or a plural suffix. _A lot of_ and _lots of_ are identical, and often written as _lotta_ or _lotsa_ in dialog, but it should always be _**a** lotta_